# JavaFX Test Error: Process 'Gradle Test Executor (number)' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, gradle, testing, javafx, junit5

I'm trying to do some unity tests in JavaFX application builded in Gradle.
I created a path called test in ../src/.
So in src I have the main package and the test package (**src/main** and **src/test**).

When I'm trying to run the test it shows this error message:

Execution failed for task ':test'.

> Process 'Gradle Test Executor 1' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[image: Error message]

I search in Stack Overflow the same error says that it's in the wrong path and what I see it isn't. Others say that is the pom.xml file without the correct dependence, but I have like 20 pom.xml files in Gradle package. Others say to downgrade the version of JUNIT5.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you "run with `--stacktrace`" to potentially get a more detailed error message?

Comment: Same happened to me after updating IntelliJ IDEA to 2022.3. Working again after downgrading to 2022.2.